# How should i install mn-fit-common in ubuntu 14

Tags: system-installation

How to install mn-fit-common in ubuntu 14,please guide me on how to enable the universe repository for the same

Comment: What is mn-fit-common? Please explain what are you trying to do.

Comment: It looks like this software is not supported for a long time.

Comment: hi. mn-fit is an interactive analysis package for fitting data and histograms generally used by physicists and mathematicians. I installed it successfully.

Comment: Then explain how you did it for everyone pls.

Comment: follow this link "http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/lucid/universe/m/mn-fit-common/install/index.html"

Comment: This link is broken, I suggest that you write an answer to your question. not just post a comment.

Answer (score 1):

First, check that the universe repository is enabled by inspecting `/etc/apt/sources.list` with your favourite editor.

You will need to use sudo to ensure that you have permissions to edit the file.

If universe is not included then modify the file so that it does.

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid main universe
```

After any changes you should run this command to update your system.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

You can now install the package like this.

```
sudo apt-get install mn-fit-common
```

Which will install mn-fit-common and any other packages on which it depends.

(The [Source](http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/lucid/universe/m/mn-fit-common/install/index.html))

Comment: followed the instructions step wise and installed mn-fit-common successfully.Thanks a lot! Hope it would help others too.

Comment: You're welcome @ArbitraryFriend